# Redefinition of Spartacus components

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I try to understand how to work with components and do not break back capability of components to have possibility get important updates from Spartacus team.

I try to understand how to make custom components and share it in between 2 Spartacus clients, any ready mechanisms?

Could you please send me maybe some links where to read it?

Answer (score 4):

Good first read is definitely the Spartacus Documentation on this topic:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/

Also, this list of not recommended practices is worth to read:
https://divante.com/blog/5-things-to-avoid-while-working-with-sap-spartacus-storefront/